# backbone js - table pagination updating all visited views

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, pagination

I'm quite new to backbone so there could be a really simple solution to this problem. I have an app where you can view a show page of which there is a table I'm adding pagination to. I have created a utility object Table to handle the pagination so it can be used on every table on each show page:

```
var Table = function(rowsStart, increment, data) {
  this.rowsStart = rowsStart;
  this.increment = increment;
  this.data = data;
  this.totalRows = _.size(data);
  this.totalRowsRoundUp = Math.ceil(_.size(data)/10)*10;
  this.paginate = function(paginateVol) {
    // Scope the figures
    this.rowsStart += paginateVol
    this.increment += paginateVol

    rS = this.rowsStart;
    inc = this.increment;

    // Show first increment results
    var rowsToDisplay = [];
    $.each(this.data, function(i,e){
      if (i < inc && i >= rS) {
        rowsToDisplay.push(e)
      }
    });
    // Send back the rows to display
    return rowsToDisplay
  };
}
```

This works fine when visiting the first show page table in the backbone history but when I visit further show pages and action this pagination object it triggers on all visited table views and produces weird results on my current view.

My View look like this:

```
// Create a view for the outer shell of our table - not inclusive of rows
queriesToolApp.ReportKeywordsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#report-queries-js',
  events: {
    'click #prev' : 'clickBack',
    'click #next' : 'clickNext'
  },
  initialize: function() {
    // compile our template
    this.template = _.template($('#tpl_indiv_report').html()); 
    // create an instance of the Table paginator object
    this.paginator = new Table(0, 10, this.collection.attributes);
  },
  render: function(paginateVol) {
    // Scope this
    _this = this;
    var data = _this.collection.attributes;
    // Render the script template
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    // Select the table body to append
    var tableBody = $('#report-queries-row');
    // Store the keyword object and the pagination amount
    var keywordObj = this.paginator.paginate(paginateVol);
    // Append keyword data to page
    $.each(keywordObj, function(index, keyword){
      // Create a new instance of the individual view 
      var reportKeywordIndView = new     queriesToolApp.ReportKeywordIndView({model: keyword})
      // append this to the table
      tableBody.append(reportKeywordIndView.render().el);
      // start table listen when last row appended
    });
  },
  clickBack: function() {
    // Render the view passing in true as it's going back
    this.render(-10);
  },
  clickNext: function() {
    // Render the view passing in nothing as default is forward
    this.render(10);
  }
})
```

Here is the individual view:

```
queriesToolApp.ReportKeywordIndView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',
  className: 'table-row',
  initialize: function() {
    // Define the template and compile the template in the view
    this.template = _.template($('#tpl_indiv_report_row').html());
  },
  render: function() {
    // Set the view with the data provided from the model
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
    return this;
  }
})
```

And I start backbone here:

```
  $(function() {
  // create a new instance of the router
  var router = new queriesToolApp.AppRouter();
  // Record the history of the url hash fragments
  Backbone.history.start();
  });
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you post code of queriesToolApp.ReportKeywordIndView and whatever is manipulating Backbone.history?

Comment: I've just added in the code!

Answer (score 0):

I think to make it work keeping the objects you defined, I'd be helpful to see the AppRouter code. One thing seems certian: the ReportKeywordIndView instances keep getting created but probably not being deleted. This could work a different way, without that extra view.

As its written here, the row view looks too simple to be a backbone view. You could probably fix this by changing the template to include the TR tag, remove the view and make some adjustments in the main view.

This can go in the initialize function:

```
this.rowTemplate = _.template($('#tpl_indiv_report_row').html());
```

This can replace the each code which creates the row view and adds it:

```
// append this to the table
     tableBody.append(_this.rowTemplate(keyword));
```